# Bash para contar carpetas en el directorio actual excluyendo otras con un nombre determinado

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

En Linux necesito contar la cantidad de carpetas que hay contenidas en la carpeta actual, excluyendo un par con estos nombres: $RECYCLE.BIN y  System Volume Information.

En total son 53 archivos sin contar los dos que necesito excluir, pero aún no logro hacer el filtro.

Lo que estoy usando ahora sería el siguiente comando:

```
ls -l | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

En general la [respuesta de blonfu](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/202024/83) funciona. Sin embargo, Linux tiene la curiosa virtud de permitir que los nombres de fichero contengan saltos de línea:

```
$ touch "hola" "hola que
> tal"
$ ls | wc -l
       3     # incorrecto, hay 2 ficheros solamente
```

Por ello, puede ser más seguro hacer un `find` que recorra todos los casos que nos interesa (es decir, solo en este nivel, sin entrar en subdirectorios) e imprima un carácter para cada fichero que encuentra. Luego, sumar caracteres:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo .' | wc -l
```

Descartando los nombres que indicas:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 ! -name '$RECYCLE.BIN' ! -name 'System Volume Information' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo .' | wc -l
```

En el caso anterior devuelve:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} sh -c 'echo .' | wc -l
       2
```

O también puedes hacer un bucle que haga lo mismo:

```
$ for f in *; do echo "."; done | wc -l
       2
```

Descartando esos nombres:

```
for f in *; do [ "$f" = '$RECYCLE.BIN' -o "$f" = 'System Volume Information' ] && continue; echo "."; done | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `grep` con el parametro `-v` para excluir los archivos o directorios que no quieres contar:

```
ls | grep -v $RECYCLE.BIN | grep -v "System Volume Information" | wc -l
```

Comment: En la mayoría de casos esto es más que suficiente. Publiqué una respuesta explicando qué hacer en los casos raros.

Comment: @fedorqui tú eres el jefe de bash pero esta me parecio sencilla aunque no pensé que `wc` lo que hace es contar líneas. Tampoco sabía que podía haber saltos de línea en los nombres de archivos